# Kotlin type missmatch. Expected Any received MyObject

Tags: android, kotlin

I am making a list of observable `LiveData` objects, that should contain `Resource` object (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html#addendum). I don't care what type of data that `Resource` object is containing.

```
abstract class LiveResources : LiveData<Resource<Any>>() {
  private val mediatorLiveData = MediatorLiveData<Resource<Any>>()
  protected val resources = HashSet<LiveData<Resource<Any>>>()

  fun addResource(source: LiveData<Resource<Any>>) {
    resources.add(source)
    mediatorLiveData.addSource(source, resourceObserver)
  }

  fun removeResource(source: LiveData<Resource<Any>>) {
    resources.remove(source)
    mediatorLiveData.removeSource(source)
  }

  private val resourceObserver = Observer<Resource<Any>> {
    onSourceChange()
  }

  abstract fun onSourceChange()
}
```

Unfortunately when I try to use `LiveResources.addResource()` with `LiveData<Resource<List<String>>>` I get TypeMismatch error in my IDE, saying that `LiveData<Resource<Any>>` was expected.

Comment: Any solution? I'm having the same issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should generify the classes to accept `Resource<T>` i.e `LiveData<Resource<T>>`. `Any` is the covariance of any object passed, but I think you are not trying to achieve that.

Another friendly advice is that you don't need to add another abstraction on top of `MediatorLiveData` that solely does the same you have implemented.

Comment: I want to make `LiveResource` don't care what kind of `LiveData<Resource<>>` is holding. Just to monitor the ERROR, and LOADING state of the Resource and change it's value.

I needed to wrap the `MediatorLiveData` so when i add new data sources to it, not to pass in observer of that change.

Answer (score 1):

Your Resource (and/or LiveData) class should be defined with generic covariance in order to make it work. Like so:

```
class Resource<out T> // <- out marks generic type as covariant
```

Comment: My Resource class is already `Resource<out T>`, however LiveData is Java class coming from Google and i cannot change it. It is declared as: `public abstract class LiveData<T>`

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it, but I think this would work

`fun <T:Any> addResource(source: LiveData<Resource<T>>)`

Comment: All `T`'s are bounded to `Any` if they don't extend other class. There is no need to bound to `Any`.

Comment: I have also tried this. While this allowed me to call `LiveResource.addResource(myResource)`, I was getting type mismatch on the `mediatorLiveData.addSource(source, resourceObserver)`

Comment: @Nikola Despotoski all T are bounded to`Any?`, not same as `Any`

Comment: This worked for me in a more general example where I wanted to pass String::class instead of String::class.java